# SQL server user session time out?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i use window application and i want to fire trigger after user session time out So ,

How to detect if user abort or his session timeout using SQ L server 2008 ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, are you saying you have a Windows Forms application and you want to implement something like the ASP.NET session? If so, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847920/how-to-implement-winform-session-like-session-timeout-especially

Comment: Session timeout is a feature of the application, not SQL Server, so how you detect it depends on your application...

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server never times out sessions nor requests. A query issued against SQL Server may run for hours, days even, uninterrupted. You may be under the wrong impression that queries against SQL Server time out and get aborted because the ADO.Net client chooses to abort queries after 30 seconds, because that is the default value of the [`SqlCommand.CommandTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout.aspx):

> The time in seconds to wait for the
>   command to execute. The default is 30
>   seconds.

However, aborting the queries is a client specific behavior that SQL Server is not involved in. Other clients (eg. JDBC) use different policies.

Similarly, a SQL Server session never times out, even if not used for days. The application has to explicitly close the connection for its sessions to terminate. While is true that there are administrative ways to disconnect sessions (the [`KILL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173730.aspx) command) these are never to be used except for extreme last measure administrative operations.

So the good news is that you don't have to do anything, what you're asking for doesn't exists, or shouldn't be done to start with.