# How to maintain a session?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C# technology. I need to maintain a session for each state in stand-alone application. My goal is to achieve a session for the purpose of timeout facility. Please guide me.

Comment: what kind of application, ASP.Net ? Winform, wpf ?

Comment: I am purely using C# only .UI is developed by C#.net. And we have maintain session in C# only.

Comment: `UI is developed by C#` - what kind of UI ? It does matter actually, if you are targeting a web application then it would differ from WinForm or desktop applicaiton

Comment: Hi habib, we are using Winform.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Explain your goals in simple terms, not a bunch of tech lingo that may or may not be relevant.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, We have a desktop application already in place. A new requirement has come in wherein if the application is idle for a given time say 10 minutes then the application should automatically logout. Application is developed in C#. Is there a easy solution wherein we don't need to touch the existing code and still implement this functionality?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Hmm, after reading your comment I suddenly realize the question did read like a marketing talk.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement winform session like session timeout especially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847920/how-to-implement-winform-session-like-session-timeout-especially)

Answer (score 2):

Winforms are inherently stateful. Variables or state you set should be available in memory as long as your calling code can access them. A global System Timer might be what you are looking for here.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847920/how-to-implement-winform-session-like-session-timeout-especially)

If you need to reinitialize a session you can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453161/best-practice-to-save-application-settings-in-a-windows-forms-application)