# Session class for windows application using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, session

Please help me with my problem. I'm starting to make a user login in winforms using C#. Since Winforns don't have sessions, I want to create a class that can check my sessions during the logs of mu users. Time they login and out. How many attempts they enter incorrect password. please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to implement winform session like session timeout especially](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847920/how-to-implement-winform-session-like-session-timeout-especially)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows application you can simply use a static class/object just to maintain user's data.

Comment: how? I'm still a student and I'm starting to learn c#. I'm confused on how to start with it

Answer (score 0):

if you need to logoff user who did not interact with application within specific time,

Winforms.Components.ApplicationIdle can acheive this goal. you need to add reference of Winforms.Components.dll in your application,

you have to read tutorial regarding Tickinterval and TickAsync of this class